# Dynamicallly building Linq "where" clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do something that can be done conventionally by writing extra lines of code. I  have seen few samples on this website that addresses my question but still i cannot put all the pieces together to solve what I am trying to achieve.

Here is pseudo code of what i am trying to do:

```
list<t> searchTerms;

class t
{
string columnName;
string columnValue ;
string columnType ;
 string FilterType;
}
```

I am using Linq to SQL to retrive data from my database and would like to build the "where" clause with list:

so something like:

```
SearchTerm t = terms.Find(term => term.ColumnValue == "PartNo");
if (t != null)
{
  switch (t.FilterType)
  {
    case FilterType.Contains:
      q = q.Where(c => c.PartNo.Contains(t.Value));
      break;

    case FilterType.EqualTo:
      q = q.Where(c => c.PartNo.Equals(t.Value));
      break;

    case FilterType.StartsWith:
      q = q.Where(c => c.PartNo.StartsWith(t.Value));
      break;
  }
}

t = terms.Find(term => term.ColumnValue == "ItemDesc");
if (t != null)
{
  switch (t.FilterType)
  {
    case FilterType.Contains:
      q = q.Where(c => c.ItemDesc.Contains(t.Value));
      break;

    case FilterType.EqualTo:
      q = q.Where(c => c.ItemDesc.Equals(t.Value));
      break;

    case FilterType.StartsWith:
      q = q.Where(c => c.ItemDesc.StartsWith(t.Value));
      break;
  }
}
```

what i would like to do is use lambda expressions/reflection to achieve something like:

```
q.whereJoinExpression(searchTerms.ToLamdaExpression());
```

where 
     searchTerms.ToLamdaExpression()

should return me the input for where clause i.e Expression>.
 and 
     whereJoinExpression should get me same result as

```
 q = q.Where(searchTerms.ToLamdaExpression());
```

I have invested a couple of days researching before posting this question and would appreciate help in the right direction.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx if you, in the future, wants to use "or" instead of "and" in your where clauses.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: But Dynamic LINQ loses all the benefits of strong typing and always seems like a cop-out solution. Something like the PredicateBuilder would be nicer, if it could be made to work.

Comment: Yup thats what i am struggling with

Comment: @sharmasu: In a dynamic query situation, typically a user would be building the query from strings anyway (selecting fields from a dropdown, for example), so I don't see how strong typing helps.